# Application crashes when capturing image on Moto G device

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-camera

I am making an Android application to capture image using Fragment. Images were captured on galaxy s2 and galaxy s4. Application did not crash on above devices. When i am testing on Moto G, the application crashes. I am getting NullPointerException. I have been stuck here for the last 2 days. I am attaching code and LogCat below. (I have made the line where the application crashed bold). Please help me.

```
10-01 11:56:47.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2998): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure        delivering result ResultInfo{who=android:fragment:0, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.as.billseeker/com.as.billseeker.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-01 11:56:47.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3432)
10-01 11:56:47.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3475)
10-01 11:56:47.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:139)
10-01 11:56:47.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1258)
10-01 11:56:47.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-01 11:56:47.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-01 11:56:47.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
10-01 11:56:47.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-01 11:56:47.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-01 11:56:47.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
10-01 11:56:47.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
10-01 11:56:47.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-01 11:56:47.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2998): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-01 11:56:47.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1420)
10-01 11:56:47.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:445)
10-01 11:56:47.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:404)
10-01 11:56:47.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at com.as.billseeker.BSPlaySuccessActivity.imageFromGallery(BSPlaySuccessActivity.java:198)
10-01 11:56:47.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at com.as.billseeker.BSPlaySuccessActivity.onActivityResult(BSPlaySuccessActivity.java:108)
10-01 11:56:47.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5450)
10-01 11:56:47.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3428)
10-01 11:56:47.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2998):     ... 11 more
```

code:

```
private String imageFromGallery(int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        //selectedImage.getPath();




**Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);**
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        return filePath;
    }
```

Edit: Answer
i had searched a lot for 2 days. finally i got answer. In moto g, There was problem with image path. i have created folder on sdcard for storing images. after that i have taken image from that path.
code:
        private static File getOutputMediaFile() {

```
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            "your_folder_name");
    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d("instaReport", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
    .format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    imagepath = mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_"
            + timeStamp + ".jpg";
    mediaFile = new File(imagepath);

    return mediaFile;
} 

private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri() {
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());
}

i have write method on button click listener:

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent( int i) {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri();
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, i);
    }
}
hope this answer helps you.
```

Comment: same with me. App crashes on moto g works fine on N4. If you got a solution for this please post it.

Comment: i updated the answer. please check